# Powershell Splitting an array of user objects into two arrays based on property

Tags: arrays, powershell

I'm trying to split up an array of user objects retrieved via `$users = Get-QADUser -searchroot 'domain.net/OU1/OU2/Users'` into two arrays based on their 'AccountIsExpired'-property.

I can do `$users = $users | where {!($_.AccountIsExpired)}` but that only gives me one part of my users. However, this does filter out some user objects.

I build this code to split  `$users` into two arrays (`$include, $exclude`):

```
[Object[]]$include = @();
[Object[]]$exclude = @();
foreach ($user in $users) {
    if (!($_.AccountIsExpired)) {
        $include += $user;
    } else {
        $exclude += $user;
    }
}
$users = $include;
```

Apart from the creation of a second array, I don't see the difference between those two bits of code...

Comment: Okay, looking at your code in a browser window sometimes is all you need to resolve your issue -.-

Here's the code that works:

[Object[]]$include = @();
[Object[]]$exclude = @();
foreach ($user in $users) {
    if (!($user.AccountIsExpired)) { # copied $_ from the where filter before...
        $include += $user;
    } else {
        $exclude += $user;
    }
}
$users = $include;
$exclude;

Comment: sorry for being unclear, thanks anyways!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about using group-object?

Something like `$groups=$users | group-object AccountIsExpired`

Comment: Yes! That looks very good, just tried it on the command line and should work in my script, too... Will try it later.